# Connecting to a database based on a course I follow

Tags: c#, sqlite, database-connection, factory, using

I’m following an online course and in the course they explain how you can retrieve data from a database. Creating the connection and commands are done by a `DbProviderFactories` class. I understand the code in the course but is using `using` for the connection, command and reader necessary? Also, are the null checks necessary? The code looks cluttered and if you have a lot of models in your database (Continent, Country, Currency, …) it would require a lot of copy/paste which is bad?

So the question really is, is the code below rather good or bad and what could be improved upon? The goal is to use SQLite as database provider. Does this work with the approach below?

```
public static ObservableCollection<Continent> GetContinents()
{
    var continents = new ObservableCollection<Continent>();
    var provider = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ProviderName;
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using (var connection = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider).CreateConnection())
    {
        if (connection == null) return null;

        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider).CreateCommand())
        {
            if (command == null) return null;

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Continent";

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                while (reader.Read())
                    continents.Add(new Continent(reader["Code"].ToString(), reader["EnglishName"].ToString()));
        }
    }

    return continents;
}
```

Comment: why would you think that it would require a lot of copy paste.. first off your CommandText should be passed in as a variable / parameter to what ever method you decide to `code for re-use` change the method signature to handle things like SqlCommand, SqlParameter, etc.. using statements are for auto disposing of objects please try to use `MSDN` and do some more research on your end as well so that you can understand outside of the online class how things work in the real world.

Comment: also there is as well as easier ways to do what you are trying to do within your own  custom DBUtils class..

Comment: you could have eliminated the while loop here and user the `DataAdapter.FIll()` method to return the contents to a `DataTable` your code is in need of some serious `Re-Factoring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using using for the connection, command and reader necessary?

Yes. 
Here I commented the code

```js
using (var command = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider).CreateCommand()) // here you've created the command
            {
                if (command == null) return null;

                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Continent";

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) //Here you're reading what the command returned.
                    while (reader.Read())
                        continents.Add(new Continent(reader["Code"].ToString(), reader["EnglishName"].ToString()));
            }
```

Also, are the null checks necessary?

> It could return null data so yes absolutely

The code looks cluttered

> Such is the coder life brotha. Using loops for objects will save on space.

Comment: what is the purpose of what you have posted here as a `NON Answer` replicating his code isn't really helping in my opinion comments could have explained this not re-posting clunky code

Comment: @MethodMan scroll to the right dude. I made comments. please +1 to compensate for your misunderstanding :p